# Launch new activity in AsyncTask in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-asynctask

I want to launch an Activity or refresh the current one from AsyncTask with Kotlin in the onPostExecute method but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried to implement an interface but I got stuck.

**interface**

```
 public interface inter {
        void newActivity(Activity activity);
    }
```

**main class**

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        ..code here
        inter {
        }
}

override fun newActivity(activity: Activity?) {
            val intent = Intent(this, Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply on **onPostExecute**

```
private class yourTask(context:Context): AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

     var context: Context = context;

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        val intent = Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

Start task as:

```
yourTask(applicationContext).execute()
```

Comment: I tried it, but I got an error because of the context